# What about business intelligence?

Tags: discussion, faq, allowed-questions

I was wondering if business intelligence has a place on this website.  In business intelligence, we can see three or four domains that relate to database expertise:

- ETL
- Data warehousing
- Data modeling
- Multidimensional databases
- etc.

Should those topics be considered on-topic for this website?

Comment: I'm for those topics. They have great value to DBAs. If they are off-topic, a new proposal will be created to settle them and this community will get weaker. I can't see any problem.

Comment: @bigown - Please post answers as answers, not as comments. We need to get everyone accustomed to the correct behaviors before the site goes public. Thanks.

Comment: @Robert: Ok. My intention was just to post an idea and not a full answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What kind of questions are allowed on Database Administrators ?](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-kind-of-questions-are-allowed-on-database-administrators)

Comment: This has now been [explicitly included][1] in scope for dba.se.


  [1]: http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/503/opinions-about-merging-the-business-intelligence-proposal-into-this-site/533#533

Answer (score 6):

I think yes.
And I want to add Reporting as with SSRS to the list. There is a lot of administration involved.

Comment: I think that we should accept anything that's about data wrangling but only where it's not necessarily also about data interpretation. This site is not about analytics, per-se. It's about accumulation and maintenance and reproduction of data.

Answer (score 4):

> In Business Intelligence we can see
>   3/4 domain that are parts of **Database
>   Expert**:
>
> - ETL
> - Datawarehousing

As long as the question is for database professionals to answer, that's fine.

From the [FAQs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/faq) page:

> Database Administrators - Stack
>   Exchange is for **database professionals**
>   who wish to improve their database
>   skills and learn from others in the
>   community

PS: I *really* wonder how many times I need to advise on [reading FAQs and About page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61039/what-advice-would-you-give-beginners-joining-a-stack-exchange-site/64943#64943).